# Python numpy not releasing swap after large calculation

Tags: python, numpy, memory, multidimensional-array

I have two large sets of arrays of `float32`

```
centers = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (64, 40, 42)).astype(dtype=np.float32)
data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (60000, 40, 42)).astype(dtype=np.float32)
```

I want to subtract each data point from each center point in this array and get the abs values. Here's one way I tried to do this

```
diff = [np.abs(data - c) for c in centers]
```

In my linux PC with a 16GB RAM and a 2GB swap, this not only gives a `MemoryError`; after crashing with the error, from `htop`, I can see that the swap space is still filled.

For the MemoryError, I rewrote the code to use slices of `data` instead of the whole array at once. (**EDIT**: No `MemoryError` now but process gets killed after sometime with `SIGKILL` it says) But it still is pretty slow and the swap not releasing still persists. **Is there a memory leak in the way I am doing this?**

**Bonus question**: Is there an efficient way of calculating the diff? It seems it takes too much time to create the arrays than to do the calculation even if I do it with slices of `data`. If I make the slices smaller, looping takes too much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I will assume you want to iterate the first dimensions of each array and compute the absolute difference among the other dimensions. If it is not what you intend to compute, please rephrase it.

### Generator

If you do not need to access all results at once, you can make use of generator to reduce the amount of memory consumed and perform computation on demand:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def generate_distance(a, b):
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(a.shape[0]), range(b.shape[0])):
        yield np.abs(a[i,:,:] - b[j,:,:])
```

Then you can get all results at once by issuing (this will consume a lot of memory as it store all results):

```
x = np.array(list(generate_distance(data, centers)))
```

Or just consume it on the fly (this will drastically reduce the amount of required memory as it will only compute the distance when needed):

```
for d in generate_distance(data, centers):
    # perform some computation on distance
```

### Memory

You can check the size of object by using:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(data)/1024**2 # 384.5216064453125 Mb
```

You can also estimate the amount of required memory if you aim to store all results, basically it will be a bit bigger than the product of dimensions by the size of the `dtype`. In your case, it would be about:

```
64*60000*40*42*4 bytes ~ 24.609,375 Mb
```

Which definitely exceed the sum of your RAM and Swap capacity.

### Workaround

So, you have few options:

- If you need to keep the results in RAM then you will have to batch process it because the complete result will not fit for the given setup;
- If you just need to have all results stored on your disk, then use generator to lower memory consumption and write distance one by one into a file;
- If you need result in RAM but not all at once, use generator to chain your computation flow and send distance on demand to another processes.

Comment: This gives me the pretty much the same result as taking chunks of `data` to calculate the diff. This and mine both codes work with smaller arrays without a problem (Yes `data` is 384Mb)

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ, Could you better explain the operation you want to perform, what is the shape of the expected results? Also could you tell us if you need all results as once or not. Because if you consume the generator on demand instead of storing all results it will drastically lower the required amount of memory.

Comment: Actually I did not want to store all the results once. I just focused on making the code faster I did not think about that. Thanks for the insight

Comment: You are welcome, out of curiosity have I implemented your computation properly? Cheers.

Comment: Your generator code must work but I wanted to calculate them in place and I wanted the difference between **one data point** to **all centers** at once. Previously I was doing **all data points** to **all centers** at once and do next calculations. So I changed the code to a loop like `for c in centers: get diff -> do calculations -> store result`